# How to pass variable in HTTPRequest Header?

Tags: java, java-http-client

I want to add header in my `HTTPRequest` with variable but it will give error not taking it but when i pass direct string value in inverted commas it work well.

Hers is the code in 3rd header i am passing variable `checksum` which contains `String` value but it is not working and if i pass direct `String` value it's work without problem.

```java
HttpRequest request1 = (HttpRequest) HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay"))
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("X-VERIFY",checksum)
                    .method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"request\":\"\"}"))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `checksum`? Maybe its value is a `String` but it's declared as something else.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Data types and values are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable explanation is that you haven't overridden `toString()` method in the class of your `checksum`. Try to override the method returning `String` value of checksum:

```java
class Checksum {
 @Override
 public String toString() {
   return value;
 }
}
```

`HttpRequestBuilder` converts an object passed into `header()` method according to certain rules and for object of custom class it just calls `toString()` method.

Comment: Checksum is not a class it just a variable which contain string value.

Comment: @NavedAhmed if that’s true, how does this answer solve your problem?